# How do I get data back from database using setInterval function in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to get data back from my database using setInterval() to do it every 60 seconds. I want to be able to get back 'message' and 'to' from my database.

my database table 'message':

```
id,  message,                 to,         from       status
1,   'hello',                'Rebecca',  'Erwin'     1
2,   'see you soon',         'Veronica', 'Erwin'     0
3,   'the party was awsome', 'Erwin',    'Rebecca'   1
4,   'can you make it?',     'Veronica', 'UNKNOWN'   1 



<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','user','pass','my_db');
    if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }

    $sql="SELECT * FROM mesage where status=1";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
?>
```

```js
function run_script() {
  cont_m = 0;
  cont_s = 0;
  s = document.getElementById("seconds");
  m = document.getElementById("minutes");
  window.setInterval(
    function() {
      if (cont_s == 60) {
        cont_s = 0;
        cont_m++;
        //get array from database, how do I run the query here get the array and display arrays?
        m.innerHTML = cont_m;
        if (cont_m == 60) {
          cont_m = 0;
        }
      }
      s.innerHTML = cont_s;
      cont_s++;
    //}, 1000); every second
    }, 100);// every 100 miliseconds for example purpose
}
```

```html
<body onload="run_script()">
  <p>
    <span id="minutes">0</span>:<span id="seconds">0</span>
  </p>
</body>
```

Comment: Requesting server using ajax every second is a no go for sure... If you want some kind of full-duplex communication, see websockets instead. Or at least, search for long polling ajax and don't use interval but a timeout calling recursive method

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run a timing event on server-side using a client-side js function? I don't think that's a very good idea. You should check other ways to do this.What you need is a [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), or something similar.